# Place <a> tag on a banner over 4 images to connect to 4 different urls

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place  tags around certain area's on a banner I have.  This banner has 4 different logos where I need a link for each one.

Banner --->>>>

ImageOne                  ImageTwo            ImageThree            ImageFour

Banner --->>>>

ImageOne Url = www.cnnsi.com

ImageTwo Url = www.cnn.com etc etc

How can I do this to where I place them in a horizontal direction?

I can do the first one without any issues, but do I need to use absolute value for the position for the remaining 3?

Here is some Css below:  if I keep the position set to: relative on #imageTwo - then it will be below the header banner which is width 999 by height 151 at the top of the page. It will place it outside of the header kinda below the #imageOne.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/Site.css"/>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2minO.js"         type="text/javascript">   
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="header" title="Test">
            <a id="imageOne" href="http://cnnsi.com" target="_blank" title="cnnsi.com"></a>
            <a id="imageTwo" href="http://cnn.com" target="_blank" title="cnn.com"></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


#imageOne {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   top: 24px;
   left: 16px;
   height: 95px;
   width: 162px;
}

#imageTwo {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 24px;
  left: 175px;
  height: 95px;
  width: 162px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use

```
float:left;
width:25%;
```

for all images,
or you can set them with

```
display:inline;
```

it will be easier if you assign one class to all images. Also, if you just remove the display:block you should be fine.
Generally you want to avoid using position:aboslute in this case.

Comment: #imageOne {
    display: inline;
 
    top: 24px;
    left: 16px;
    height: 95px;
    width: 162px;
}

#imageTwo {
    display: inline;
 
    top: 24px;
    left: 260px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 230px;
}

#imageThree {
    display: inline;  
    top: 68px;
    left: 575px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 146px;
}    I did the following, but no urls a tags are showing up now?

Comment: I think I might be looking for display: inline-block:  I'll let you know.